# CHKDSK takes hours – is it safe to terminate it?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, chkdsk

```
Corruption was found while examining files in directory ...
```

It's been close to 7 hours and still going. I think it started because I was moving GBs of files from my rusty notebook into my 2 TB external HD and for some reason my notebook suddenly went to sleep midway and failed to wake up, forced me to hard reboot it, thus causing the termination of the writing process and then I can't copy anything into it.

Then I ran `chkdsk /f` on the HD and after a while the above message continues to appear. My HD has lots of small files like images (from chapters of comics) and songs, I'm not sure if that affects the scanning duration. It's scanning my comics directory now, and looking at the chapter number it's probably barely 10%.

I want to run the CHKDSK on a better PC (with better port) so it could finish quicker. I heard it's safe if I stop the process in the reading stage, but I'm not even sure which stage is it on now. So, is it safe to terminate the CHKDSK at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't interrupt CHKDSK if you can avoid it.  Now that it's started, it's best to leave it until finished.  Now you know for the future, it's good to do it on a desktop PC you can just leave running.
Future versions of Windows will be moving over to ReFS instead of NTFS.  One of the benefits is that it constantly checks your files and file system integrity, so that you don't have to run NTFS CHKDSK.